# Гугл карта загрузка маркеров при движении карты

Tags: java, android

Есть карта, на ней куча маркеров. Сейчас карта загружается и через колбак реагирует, когда вырубать прогресс диалог. А маркеры загружаются потом. Как сделать так, чтобы при движении карты подгружались маркеры, которые находятся в данном районе карты? Или подскажите как убрать загрузку маркеров в прогресс диалог?

```
myProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
myProgress.setTitle("Карта загружается");
myProgress.show();

mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
onMapReady2(googleMap);
}});

 public void onMapReady2(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            myProgress.dismiss();
 }
 });
 }
```

Comment: Лично я не понял вопроса, вы можете отслеживать нажатие на карту. 
У листнера карты есть метод onMapClick, который возвращает координаты тапа, вы можете его использовать. Также вы у своей карты всегда можете получить видимую область на данный момент, зум, etc. 
Даже зная это уже не составит труда сделать что вы задумали, но с маркерами я не понял до конца.

Answer (score 1):

Вам поможет objectManager. Он сам понимает какие объекты скрывать, а какие показывать.
[objectManager](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager)

Comment: Если хотите руками делать то тогда вот пример: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/show_visible_objects

Comment: а как objectManager работает с гугло-картой?

Comment: @ivanVovk, прошу прощения, не заметил, что про гугл карту вопрос